# Operating System Management Tasks - Processor management

Tags: operating-system, processor, pairing

I came across this explanation for processor management in OS:

Processor management which involves putting the tasks into order and **pairing them into manageable size** before they go to the CPU.

what does "pairing them into manageable size" actually mean? why does the word **"pairing"** is used here ?

Comment: Read a good book, like [this one](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) or [this](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Tanenbaum-Modern-Operating-Systems-4th-Edition/PGM80736.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ref: The sentence seems to have come from this book: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=7GzJDQAAQBAJ

> what does "pairing them into manageable size" actually mean? why does the word "pairing" is used here ?

I doubt the author of the book knows what they're talking about, and (until/unless the author provides a better explanation) I would assume they just plucked some random words out of thin air to indicate that an OS does "stuff" to manage processors.

The reality is that "processor management" can be split into multiple parts (detecting CPUs and their features, configuration of CPUs, managing "speed vs. power consumption/heat", handling CPU failures, scheduling, etc) and none of those parts involve "pairing tasks into manageable size".

Note that the author doesn't seem to have a firm grasp of English (for an example, see the Preface - at least 3 errors in 4 sentences); so maybe they used the word "pairing" when they meant something else entirely.